# How form works as an alternative to message box to prevent form closing in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms, formclosing

I want to ask how I can make the new form works as an alternative to message box dialog to prevent the form closing in VB.NET?

Well, I create a new form that when the [X] button is click, it will popup and confirm if the user is really want to exit the program.

The form that will popup if the [X] button is click I design is similar to Message Dialog Yes/No, I used two picture box as the Yes and No of my form.

I used this code in the Yes and No picture box in the form that will popup:

```
Private Sub picxyes_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles picxyes.Click

        Main.Close()
        about.Close()
        Me.Close()

    End Sub

Private Sub picxno_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles picxno.Click
        Me.Close()
```

And this in form closing event:

```
e.Cancel = true
exitgame.Show()

'exitgame is the name of the form that will popup when [x] is click.
```

I also try to add a e.Cancel = False under the Private Sub picxyes_Click but it says error.

I need to know how can I used this  picture box (picxyes and picxno) that when picxyes is click, the e.Cancel must be turn into false and whole form must close, otherwise, when picxno is click, only exitgame form will close? Please share any ideas that might help this. Thank you.

Comment: design your replacement form as a dialog to return `DialogResult.xxx` then evaluate that return in the main form to decide whether to close or not...MessageBox can do the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MessageBox.Show() displays a *dialog*.  You want to create a dialog as well:

```
Private Sub picxyes_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles picxyes.Click
    Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
End Sub

Private Sub picxno_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles picxno.Click
    Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
End Sub
```

Now you can simply use the DialogResult, like you do for MessageBox, in your FormClosing event handler:

```
    If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing Then
        Using dlg = New ExitGame
            If dlg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then e.Cancel = True
        End Using
    End If
```